# Unable to reshape numpy array to RGB image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I have an numpy array which is of all images from CIFAR10 dataset:
`(50000, 3072)`

I am taking a single array out of it, its shape is `(3072,)`
then am trying to convert it to RGB image by doing
`.reshape(32, 32, 3)`

But when I pass it to plt.show() it shows something like[image]

I am not sure why it is not showing the image correctly, I also tried
`.reshape(3, 32, 32)` but it gives `TypeError: Invalid shape (3, 32, 32) for image data` while plotting

How do I reshape it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `np.swapaxes()` to get valid shape for `plt.imshow()` to accept.

```
import numpy as np
dd = np.array([1]*3072).reshape(3, 32, 32)
dd1 = np.swapaxes(dd, 0, 2)
```

Try  `plt.imshow(dd1)` to see what happens. (use your own data) :p

First of all, you should reshape using (3, 32, 32), this is determine by order of your data.

Then you have to display the reshape image, but `plt.imshow()` only accepts array with the shape (M, N) or (M, N, 3) or (M, N, 4), so you have to swap axes now as the reshaped data is (3, 32, 32). Details see [plt.imshow](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) and [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html)

Comment: the plotted image is rotated 90 degree anti-clockwise

Comment: You can flip or transpose you image using `np.flip`, not sure which one is good for you:)

Comment: @batman using `np.rot90(dd1, 3)` worked for me, here I am rotating the image by 270 degrees.

Comment: I think this will only work if the image is square. If there is an image, ```img```, in the form (3,M,N) where M != N then multiple swapaxes function calls are needed to reshape it into (M,N,3) like this: ```np.swapaxes(np.swapaxes(img, 0, 1), 1, 2)```